# What libraries do I need to write a desktop application for Raspbian with Visual Studio "C++ for Linux" and remote GDB Debugging?

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi, debian, raspbian

So I bought a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B that I run Raspbian on. I found [this tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/30/visual-c-for-linux-development/) and I've managed to connect to my RPi from Visual Studio and run the example program that was included in the extension. But the library that that program uses is [WiringPi](http://wiringpi.com/) which only seems to include functionality for very basic stuff, like digitalWrite and that...

I want to open an OpenGL window on Raspbian and be able to control the OS and not just the Pi itself. I've googled a lot and I just can't find anything, or I just don't know what the right thing to google is... Can some experienced Raspberry Pi geek out there help me?

Comment: I hope so. Not being a Pi Guy but shaving served in the embedded trenches for a long, long time, I suggest  mocking up the Pi on your PC and doing the bulk of your debugging on the PC. You'll still have timing weirds and hardware specific nasties to knock out, but if you can eliminate the application logic from what you have to debug on the Pi you'll almost certainly come out ahead.

Comment: While interesting, this Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related site http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ .  see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . AND consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.